# Convert text dataset to .arff file

Tags: converters, weka, text-mining, text-classification, arff

I have this data set https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Sentiment+Labelled+Sentences

and I need to convert it from .txt to .arff file to make classification with weka program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a programming language.

It's not hard to write a program that

1. reads the input format line by line
2. outputs the arff header
3. outputs the data in arff sparse vector format

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know what is csv file.

```
 public void Convert(String Path, String Directory, String Filename) throws Exception{
   String InputFilename = Path + Filename+".csv";
    // load CSV
    CSVLoader loader = new CSVLoader();
    loader.setSource(new File(InputFilename));
    Instances data = loader.getDataSet();

    // save ARFF
    ArffSaver saver = new ArffSaver();
    saver.setInstances(data);
    String FileT = Filename;
    saver.setFile(new File(Path+Directory+"\\"+FileT));
    saver.writeBatch();
```